malloc sysmalloc assertion error every once in a while
I am writing a multiprocessing C program in Linux using message queues and signals. and sometimes the following error pops up in the terminal.
error:

scheduler.out: malloc.c:2617: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

code:
Process* stringtoProcess(char* str) {
    Process* p = malloc(sizeof(Process));
    sscanf(str, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s", &p->id, &p->arrival, &p->startTime, &p->runtime, &p->priority, &p->WaitingTime, &p->remainingTime, p->state);
    return p;
}

void receiveProcess() {
    key_t key_up, key_down;
    int msgid_up, msgid_down;
    struct msgbuf buffer_up, buffer_down;
    key_up = ftok("keyfile", 'A');
    key_down = ftok("keyfile", 'Z');
    if (key_up == -1 || key_down == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    msgid_up = msgget(key_up, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    msgid_down = msgget(key_down, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (msgid_up == -1 || msgid_down == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&buffer_up, 0, sizeof(buffer_up));
    memset(&buffer_down, 0, sizeof(buffer_down));
    if (msgrcv(msgid_up, &buffer_up, sizeof(buffer_up.mtext), 5, !IPC_NOWAIT) == -1) {
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Process *p = stringtoProcess(buffer_up.mtext);
    TotalRunTime += p->runtime;
    if(FirstArrival == -1)
    FirstArrival = p->arrival;
    if(algo == 1)
        enqueue(ready_queue, p);
    else push(ready_queue, p, prio_flag);
    buffer_down.mtype = 5;
    if(msgsnd(msgid_down, &buffer_down, sizeof(buffer_down.mtext), 5) == -1) {
        perror("msgsend");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

here is the process struct
typedef struct Process {
    int id;
    int pid;
    int arrival;
    int startTime;
    int runtime;
    int priority;
    int WaitingTime;
    int remainingTime;
    char state[20];
    int Sent;
} Process;

the receiveProcess function is a signal handler which is called multiple times consecutively (about 1 - 5 times). and I have found after some debugging is that this error happens in the third time or fourth time it enters the function.
keep in mind that usually it doesn't happen at all.

It sounds like you're writing outside of allocated memory, or to freed memory.

the receiveProcess function is a signal handler Your code is unsafe. Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions.  POSIX allows for the calling of "async-signal-safe" functions only when within a signal handler.  Not one of msgget(), perror(), exit(), msgrcv(), or msgsnd() are async-signal-safe.  It is unsafe to call any of them from within a signal handler. enqueue()andpush()` are also likely unsafe.

Add malloc to @AndrewHenle's list of not guaranteed async-signal-safe calls, which you are calling via stringtoProcess()

@AviBerger I missed that.  And malloc() is probably the worst possible call that can be made from a signal handler.

See How to avoid calling printf() in a signal handler? — noting that it is not only printf() that should not be called from a signal handler.  Also, a signal handler function should have the signature void handler(int signum) — it is passed a signal number.  Omitting the argument is unlikely to break anything, but it is not strictly correct.  If you're using sigaction() with SA_SIGINFO, the interface to the signal handler is more complex.

You should check the return value from sscanf() to ensure that all the expected values were converted.  The Process structure has 10 fields; the stringToProcess() function only sets 8 of them — so there are two uninitialized fields in the value returned by stringToProcess(); that's not good either.  And sscanf() is not async-signal safe.

There are multiple problems with your code.


 Process* stringtoProcess(char* str) {
     Process* p = malloc(sizeof(Process));
     sscanf(str, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s", &p->id, &p->arrival, &p->startTime, &p->runtime, &p->priority, &p->WaitingTime, &p->remainingTime, p->state);
     return p;
 }

There are 2 problems here. You're not checking whether malloc() was successful, and you're writing uninitialized memory to str.

If we confine ourselves to the ISO C Standard, there's very little that can be done in a signal handler. However, your code assumes POSIX support, so I won't go into specifics. Unlike the C Standard, the POSIX Standard specifies a lot of functions as async-signal-safe, but ftok(), perror(), exit(), msgget(), msgrcv(), malloc(), sscanf(), and msgsnd() are not among them.
The functions enqueue() and push() are likely also async-signal-unsafe. Note that the functions called by a signal handler themselves should not call async-signal-unsafe functions, unlike stringtoProcess(), which calls malloc() and sscanf().

The signature of a signal handler is:
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

Your receiveProcess() function does not conform to it.

You're ignoring the return value of sscanf(), and are leaving two members of the Process struct uninitialized.


In short, your code invokes undefined behavior in multiple places, and its behavior is not predictable.
